# Inline email attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is a way to inline an attachment using ruby 1.# and rails 1.#

I'm able to attach the file with the email, but I want to display the image within the email (inline)

```
    attachment :content_type => "image/jpeg",  :body => File.read(_directory), :filename => _filename
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a gem that does this in older Rails - not sure about 1.x (was written against 2.x) - but it's worth a try: http://github.com/smathy/inline_attachment